# ggplot2 y-axis order changes after subsetting

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-factor

I have a function that works as expected until I subset it. The function, plotCalendar() is my attempt at a Calendar Heat Map using ggplot2 with facets. The y-axis order is important because it is for the "WeekOfMonth" - when the order is reversed the data viz does not look like a calendar.

The code is below, first the calling code, then the function to generate some data - generateData(), then the plot function - plotCalendar()

The code works as expected when I used df for the data but when I used df2, the subsetted data, the order of the WeekOfMonth is reversed along the y-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ProgGUIinR)
library(chron)

df <- generateData()
plotCalendar(df, dateFieldName = "dates", numericFieldName = "counts", yLab = "Month of Year")
df2 <- df[df$filterField == 42, ]
plotCalendar(df2, dateFieldName = "dates", numericFieldName = "counts", yLab = "Month of Year")
```

## The two functions, one to generate test data, the other to plot the Calendar

```
generateData <- function()
{
      set.seed(42)
      dates <- seq(as.Date("2012/01/01"), as.Date("2012/6/30"), by = "1 day")
      counts <- 1:length(dates)
      filterField <- sample(1:42,length(dates),replace=T)
      df <- data.frame(dates, counts, filterField)

      return(df)
}


plotCalendar <- function(data, dateFieldName, numericFieldName, title = "Title", yLab = "Y Label", fillLab = "Fill Label", lowColor = "moccasin", highColor = "dodgerblue")
{

      agg <- aggregate(as.formula(paste(numericFieldName, "~", dateFieldName)), data, sum)

      names(agg)[names(agg) == dateFieldName] <- "DateField"
      names(agg)[names(agg) == numericFieldName] <- "NumericField"

      minMonth <- as.POSIXlt(min(agg$DateField))$mon + 1
      maxMonth <- as.POSIXlt(max(agg$DateField))$mon + 1

      minYear <- as.POSIXlt(min(agg$DateField))$year + 1900
      maxYear <- as.POSIXlt(max(agg$DateField))$year + 1900 

      minDate <- ISOdate(minYear, minMonth, 1)
      maxDate <- ISOdate(maxYear, maxMonth, 1)
      maxDateEndMonth <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(seq(maxDate, length = 2, by = "1 month")[2]))
      daySeq <- seq(minDate, maxDateEndMonth, by = "1 day")

      daySeq <- as.data.frame(daySeq)
      names(daySeq) <- c("DateField")
      daySeq$DateField <- as.Date(daySeq$DateField)
      agg$DateField <- as.Date(agg$DateField)

      agg <- merge(daySeq, agg, by = "DateField", all.x = T)

      agg$Day <- as.numeric(days(agg$DateField))

      agg$Weekday <- weekdays(agg$DateField)
      agg$Weekday <- factor(agg$Weekday, levels = rev(c("Saturday", "Friday", "Thursday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday", "Monday", "Sunday")))

      agg$Month <- months(agg$DateField)
      agg$Month <- factor(agg$Month, levels = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"))

      agg$MonthNumber <- as.POSIXlt(agg$DateField)$mon + 1

      agg$Year <-  as.POSIXlt(agg$DateField)$year + 1900

      agg$WeekOfMonth <- 1 + week.of.month(agg$Year, agg$MonthNumber, agg$Day)
      agg$WeekOfMonth <- factor(agg$WeekOfMonth, levels = 6:1)

      #makeSpreadsheet(gActs, "Group Activities - Member Participation")

      View(agg)
      p <- ggplot(agg)
      p <- p + aes(Year, WeekOfMonth, fill = NumericField)

      noData <- subset(agg, is.na(agg$NumericField))

      p <- p + geom_tile(data = subset(agg, !is.na(agg$NumericField)), aes(fill = NumericField), color = "gray")
      if(nrow(noData) > 0)
      {
        p <- p + geom_tile(data = noData, color = "gray", fill = "white")
      }

      p <- p + geom_text(aes(label = paste(paste(rep(" ", 5), collapse = ""), Day)), vjust = 0, size = 3, colour = "black")
      p <- p + geom_text(data = subset(agg, !is.na(NumericField)), aes(label = NumericField), size = 4, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1, color = 'black', fontface = "bold")
      p <- p + facet_grid(Month ~ Weekday) + scale_fill_gradient(low = lowColor, high = highColor)
      p <- p + labs(title = paste(title, "\n"), y = paste(yLab, "\n"), fill = fillLab)
      p <- p + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face="bold"),  
                     axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
                     axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
                     axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                     axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"), 
                     legend.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"), 
                     legend.text = element_text(size = 11),
                     panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                     strip.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"))
      plot(p)
}
```

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: I can't run your code. You have some undefined functions. Are you  using any other packages?

Comment: the `if (nrow(noData) > 0)` line is where things are messing up, I think the problem is that if nrow(noData) > 0 is TRUE, then you are adding another layer of `geom_tile` on top of an existing one. To fix the reverse ordering, you can put the geom_tiles in an if-else, i.e., `if (nrow(noData) > 0) {do one thing} else {do another}`; but I'm not sure if that is how you want the calendar to look. Otherwise, you can add `+ scale_y_discrete(breaks = 5:1, labels = 1:5)` inside the `if nrow` but that is more brute-force hacky I suppose.

Comment: Thank you rawr for your answer. My goal was to have another color when there was no data. But I didn't need to test for no data, all I had to do was put the layer for no data before the layer for cases when there was data. I was able to get it to work by removing the noData variable and the if statement and its block. If got the look of the Calendar that I wanted with these two lines: 

p <- p + geom_tile(data = agg, color = "gray", fill = "white");
p <- p + geom_tile(data = subset(agg, !is.na(agg$NumericField)), aes(fill = NumericField), color = "gray")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you reverse the order of the to tile layers, it works.

Current:

```
p <- ggplot(agg, aes(Year, WeekOfMonth, fill = NumericField))
noData <- subset(agg, is.na(agg$NumericField))
p <- p + geom_tile(data = subset(agg, !is.na(agg$NumericField)), aes(fill = NumericField), color = "gray")
if(nrow(noData) > 0) p <- p + geom_tile(data = noData, color = "gray", fill = "white")
```

New:

```
p <- ggplot(agg,aes(Year, WeekOfMonth, fill = NumericField))  
noData <- subset(agg, is.na(agg$NumericField)) 
if(nrow(noData) > 0) p <- p + geom_tile(data = noData, color = "gray", fill = "white")
p <- p + geom_tile(data = subset(agg, !is.na(agg$NumericField)), aes(fill = NumericField), color = "gray")
```

[image]

I think the problem is to do with ggplot's treatment of factors,e.g., `agg$WeekOfMonth`, that have missing levels. One way around this is to avoid making `agg$WeekOfMonth` a factor.

```
agg$WeekOfMonth <- 1 + week.of.month(agg$Year, agg$MonthNumber, agg$Day)
p <- ggplot(agg)
p <- p + aes(Year, -WeekOfMonth, fill = NumericField)  
noData <- subset(agg, is.na(agg$NumericField))
p <- p + geom_tile(data = subset(agg, !is.na(agg$NumericField)), aes(fill = NumericField), color = "gray")
if(nrow(noData) > 0)p <- p + geom_tile(data = noData, color = "gray", fill = "white")
```

To avoid negative y-axis labels, you have to add:

```
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(label=abs)
```

to the `ggplot` layer definitions. This produces the same plot as above, and does not require reversing the order of the tile layers.

**EDIT** Found a *much better way to do this*.

By using the `na.value-...` argument to `scale_fill_continuous(...)` you can avoid multiple datasets completely.

```
p <- ggplot(agg)
p <- p + aes(Year, WeekOfMonth, fill = NumericField)
p <- p + geom_tile(aes(fill = NumericField), color = "gray")
p <- p + scale_fill_gradient(low = lowColor, high = highColor, na.value="white")
```

This avoids the need for `noData` altogether.

Finally, I suppose you have a reason for displaying the calendars this way, but IMO here is a more intuitive calendar view.

[image]

[image]

```
gg.calendar <- function(df) {
  require(ggplot2)
  require(lubridate)
  wom <- function(date) { # week-of-month
    first <- wday(as.Date(paste(year(date),month(date),1,sep="-")))
    return((mday(date)+(first-2)) %/% 7+1)
  }
  df$month <- month(df$dates)
  df$day   <- mday(df$dates)

  rng   <- range(df$dates)
  rng   <- as.Date(paste(year(rng),month(rng),1,sep="-"))
  start <- rng[1]
  end   <- rng[2]
  month(end) <- month(end)+1
  day(end)   <- day(end)  -1

  cal <- data.frame(dates=seq(start,end,by="day"))
  cal$year  <- year(cal$dates)
  cal$month <- month(cal$dates)
  cal$cmonth<- month(cal$dates,label=T)
  cal$day   <- mday(cal$dates)
  cal$cdow  <- wday(cal$dates,label=T)
  cal$dow   <- wday(cal$dates)
  cal$week  <- wom(cal$dates)

  cal        <- merge(cal,df[,c("dates","counts")],all.x=T)

  ggplot(cal, aes(x=cdow,y=-week))+
    geom_tile(aes(fill=counts,colour="grey50"))+
    geom_text(aes(label=day),size=3,colour="grey20")+
    facet_wrap(~cmonth, ncol=3)+
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "moccasin", high = "dodgerblue", na.value="white")+
    scale_color_manual(guide=F,values="grey50")+
    scale_x_discrete(labels=c("S","M","T","W","Th","F","S"))+
    theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
    theme(panel.grid=element_blank())+
    labs(x="",y="")+
    coord_fixed()
}
gg.calendar(df)
gg.calendar(df2)
```

Comment: See my edit at the bottom. There is a much better way.