# fill ggplot2 calender heat map by month

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a calendar heat map in ggplot2 but I want to color it by month of the year. The heat map looks something like this: [image] and the code I got is:

```
ggplot(cal, aes(x=cdow,y=-week))+
geom_tile(aes(fill=counts,colour="grey50"))+
geom_text(aes(label=day),size=3,colour="grey20")+
facet_wrap(~cmonth, ncol=3)+
scale_fill_gradient(low = "moccasin", high = "dodgerblue", na.value="white")+
scale_color_manual(guide=F,values="grey50")+
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("S","M","T","W","Th","F","S"))+
theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
theme(panel.grid=element_blank())+
labs(x="",y="")+
coord_fixed()
```

I got it from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478497/ggplot2-y-axis-order-changes-after-subsetting). Is there any way that I can give each month a different color regardless of count? e.g. have the same color for Jan-Mar, and a different one for Apr-Jun.

Any pointers would be immensely helpful!! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested as we don't have any reproducible data, but the following should do it :

```
ggplot(cal, aes(x=cdow,y=-week))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=cmonth,colour="grey50"))+
  geom_text(aes(label=day),size=3,colour="grey20")+
  facet_wrap(~cmonth, ncol=3)+
  scale_fill_discrete()+
  scale_color_manual(guide=F,values="grey50")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("S","M","T","W","Th","F","S"))+
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank())+
  labs(x="",y="")+
  coord_fixed()
```

I just changed `fill=counts` to `fill=cmonth` in `geom_tile()`, and `scale_fill_gradient` to `scale_fill_discrete`.

Comment: thanks Juba I'm trying to get it to work first with the sample data from the question whose link I posted. I have tried to change `fill` and `scale_fill` but it doesnt work I get an error: `Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting'